# WPF C# adding event handler programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, events, textbox, handler

In my code I create an array of TextBoxes :

```
namespace TCalc
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public TextBox[] pubAltArray;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pubAltArray = new TextBox[10];
```

Then I create the TextBoxes programmatically using the following code :

```
private void generatePublishedTxtBox()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TextBox pubAlt = new TextBox();
        grid_profile.Children.Add(pubAlt);
        pubAlt.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
        ...
        pubAltArray[i] = pubAlt;
    }
}
```

Than I have some routine I want to run when the content of each TextBox changes :

```
private void doTheStuff(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
...
}
```

So I tried to add event handler during the definition of new TextBox however without success :

```
pubAlt.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(doTheStuff());
```

or

```
pubAlt.TextChanged += RoutedEventHandler(calculateCorAlts());
```

Any hint for me?

Comment: this is a basic understanding about c# other than anything else. I can imagine that you'll have a hard time experiencing WPF (unless you are some XAML designer but now want to learn C#).

Comment: Carefully inspect what the debugger says and google it before ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
pubAlt.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(doTheStuff);
```

or:

```
pubAlt.TextChanged += doTheStuff;
```

Both lines do the same thing. The second one is just shorthand for the first line since it makes code easier to read.

Comment: That is actually what I have there, made and error when trying to simplify the code for the question. Anyway I receive an error CS0123  C# No overload for 'doTheStuff' matches delegate 'TextChangedEventHandler'. Thanks

Comment: your doTheStuff method must have the following signature: `void doTheStuff(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)`. Make sure that the namespace you're using for `TextChangedEventArgs` is correct.

Comment: This actually did the stuff! Could you please explain why do I need to add the System.Windows.Controls in such case?

Comment: You should read up on namespaces. There is plenty of information available on the web. That'll answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the method using `()`. Change your code to be like this:

```
pubAlt.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler((s,e) => doTheStuff());
pubAlt.TextChanged += RoutedEventHandler((s,e) =>calculateCorAlts());
```

Your method are not matching what it was asking for.

Comment: That is actually what I have there, made and error when trying to simplify the code for the question. Anyway I receive an error CS0123  C# No overload for 'doTheStuff' matches delegate 'TextChangedEventHandler' Thanks

Comment: I updated the code. I assume you had your parameter the same as the event handler.